# How to Implement Lifecycle Events With Existing Code

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding how to correctly use React Class Lifecycle functions.

I've created an email input field that, upon validation, changes submit button styling. Everything works as [seen in this Codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/WNeXKya) . However I haven't included any lifecycle methods like `ComponentDidMount` and feel this could cause issues down the road.

Question is, what is the correct 'React' way of creating what I have in Codepen?

Comment: Please also inline the code in your questions so others do not have to leave the site to view it: This also makes sure that your question will stay meaningful to others if the link is down in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your component works as desired without implementing any lifecycle methods, you probably don't need them (yet; until perhaps your component becomes more complex). You don't have to worry about it causing issues down the road, because you can add them *as needed*.

If you want to know more about how and when to add lifecycles to a class, it's best to refer to the official docs for [adding lifecycle methods to a class](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class).

Note that nowadays many people prefer function based components with the use of so called *hooks* instead of the traditional lifecycle methods, because of its low footprint in the component. You can read about them in the official [docs for hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

As for how to otherwise improve your implementation; you could simplify your onchange method to be something like this:

```js
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
}
```

Which sets the state for the relevant field, based on it's name property.

Answer (score 0):

A React component does not require the use of any of the lifecycle methods to work properly. Using them is entirely optional and you only need them for certain use cases and yours doesn't seem to be one of them.